# How to mock dynamic (toD) endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

Hy all,

suppose I have to following production code:

```
from("file:/home/test/from/")
  .setHeader("targetDynamicEndpoint", constant("file:/home/test/to/"))
  .toD("${header.targetDynamicEndpoint}")
```

How would I be able to mock the producer endpoint ('toD')?

I would be able to guess the string passed to the 'toD', because its set via StringBoot properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a test you could use [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) and call the method weaveByType

for example:

```
camelContext.getRouteDefinition("routeId").adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            weaveByType(ToDynamicDefinition.class).replace().to("mock:someMock")
        }
    });

MockEndpoint someMockEndpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:someMock", MockEndpoint.class);
```

or you could even give the producer endpoint an id and use the method weaveById

Comment: how can you weave when you have multiple toD in the route, is it possible to filter somehow?

Comment: @Zoltan you can give the endpoint and id: `.toD(...).id("endpoint1")` and then do `weaveById("endpoint1")` in your test